# Wait until element is visible Safari 10 throws exception

Tags: java, selenium, safari

I was using below code for the safari 9

```
WebDriverWait waitForElementVisibility = new WebDriverWait(dr, 10); 
waitForElementVisibility.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element));
```

When i updated safari to 10 , it throws exception : element not found exception.
Same code works with chrome and IE

Comment: Is this just for a specific element? Or is it any element? Have you tried different selectors? There is probably too little detail here for anyone to be helpful.